# why cant I create a handle in activity.oncreate()?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHBWX.png)

IDEA cant get me a advance,but why?

Comment: And what on hell is `Handle`?

Comment: You wrote Handle instead of Handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
Handler handle = new Handler();
```

Comment: That assumes Handle is a typo for Handler: if Handle is a custom class or in a library, Handler is the wrong class

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right, but the author did not respond yet, we can't know, but thank you

Comment: oh no ,it's all my fault.....